# Grails save problems

Tags: grails, save

This has been an issue for a few weeks and no one has managed to figure out the problem.

When I populate the database I do so by reading in and parsing an excel sheet.

For each line a create a product

Domains:

```
class Product {
      String name
      String comments
      static hasMany = [components:Components]
}

class Components {
      Product product
      static hasMany = [alternatives:Alternatives]
}

class Alternatives {
      Product product
}
```

I create an instance like this:

```
 Product p = new Product(name: getCell(1).getStringVale(),
                         comments: getCell(2).getStringValue(),
                         components: [])

 Components c = new Components(product: Product.get(getCell(3).getIntegerValue()),
                                alternatives = [])

 c.alternatives.add(new Alternatives(product: Product.get(getCell(4).getIntegerValue())).save(failOnError:true,flush:true))
 c.alternatives.add(new Alternatives(product: Product.get(getCell(5).getIntegerValue())).save(failOnError:true,flush:true))

 p.components.add(c)

 c.save(failOnError:true,flush:true)
 p.save(failOnError:true,flush:true)
```

Now if I print this out right away like the following assuming the ID of that product was set to 1:

```
XML.use("deep")
Println Product.get(1) as XML
```

This works fine and seems to have saved to the database.

If I then look at the database there are no/or random relationships being set.
It is worth noting that the products are saved as part of a loop.

Has anyone experienced anything like this before?

Comment: Is there a reason you are calling `c.alternatives.add(...)` instead of `c.addToAlternatives(...)` and `p.components.add(...)` instead of `p.addToComponents(...)`?

Comment: `Product.get(getCell(4).getIntegerValue()).save(failOnError:true,flush:true)` doesn't make sense.  It looks like you are retrieving a Product from the database and then immediately calling `save` on that instance.  Why are you doing that?

Comment: A spreadsheet not a database

Comment: "A spreadsheet not a database" - The call to `Product.get(...)` is retrieving information from a spreadsheet?

Comment: I see the problem you was referring to I have edited it.
I am also trying the .addTo as well, thank you for this. I have a feeling this is the issue.

Comment: You have code that is invoking `Product.get(...).save(...)`.  That is the bit that doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Jeff you were correct with your first comment. I needed to use addTo. Thanks for this.

Answer (score 1):

Use `c.addToAlterntives(...)` and `p.addToComponents(...)` instead of `c.alternatives.add(...)` and `p.components.add(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you have a validation issue.  If you print it immediately you are just seeing the transient data stored in your domain object.

When you save do this:

```
if (!object.save()) {
    println("ERRORS: ")
    object.errors.allErrors.each {
        println "\tERROR: ${it}"
    }
}
```

See if that will show you what is going wrong.  You can also call `object.validate` to see if they validate or not.  Hope this helps!  I have had similar problems before.  Happy coding!

Comment: The original description says that random relationships are being saved.  That suggests that this is unlikely to be a validation issue and more likely to be problem with the way the surrounding code is organized.  Validation issues would not result in random relationships being saved.